# Eclipse c++ method could not be resolved

Tags: c++, methods, resolve

Header:

```
#ifndef patientenliste_hpp
#define patientenliste_hpp

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "patient.hpp"

using namespace std;

class Patientenliste
{
private:
    vector<Patient> liste;

public:
    Patientenliste& operator+= (const Patient&);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Patientenliste&);
};


ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Patientenliste&);

#endif
```

Sourcecode:

```
#include "patientenliste.hpp"


Patientenliste::Patientenliste& operator+= (const Patient& p)
{
    liste.push_back(p);
    return *this;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Patientenliste& p)
{
    for(auto& i : p.liste)
        os << i;

    return os;
}
```

Why do I have to put "Patientenliste::" before "liste" in the operator definition += in the Sourcecode? Eclipse can't resolve it, but it should do, isn't it?
Worked fine with my previous project...

Comment: What do you mean ecliipse cannot resolve it? Do you expect the autocomplete wizard to do it for you automatically? Putting "Patientenliste::" before liste in the operator definition += is a basic class definition thing in C++. It has nothing to do with Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
Patientenliste::Patientenliste& operator+= (const Patient& p)
```

should be

```
Patientenliste& Patientenliste::operator+= (const Patient& p)
```

You are using `Patientenliste::` as operator+= is in scope of that class i.e member of that class.